# How to read HTML file and store its content into UITableView cell?

Tags: html, file

I have a HTML file containing Terms and conditions of signup process of my app. I want to show all the contents of that file in normal text format onto Table cell. How it can be implemented ?

Thanks in advance.
I am also thankful for last answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to create one Customcell for doing this...

And for this, take new file with UITableViewCell class and remove view and add UITableViewCell in it..and then take UIWebView in this XIB file..

and set IBOutlets properly...

and For displaying html file in UIWebView please follow this [Link](http://zaldzbugz.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/access-local-html-file-to-show-in-uiwebview/)